# How do I speed up a SQL query that uses a BETWEEN condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID    StartRange    EndRange
----------------------------
 1        1            3
 2        4            8
 3        9           12
```

And so on and so forth, so that there are over 5 million records. The last record looks something like this:

```
ID        StartRange    EndRange
---------------------------------
5235976   9894727374   9894727378
```

In other words, the `StartRange` and `EndRange` will never overlap for each record.

I need to do a query that finds the corresponding ID of a number that matches the range:

```
SELECT ID FROM BigTable WHERE '5000000' BETWEEN StartRange AND EndRange;
```

Unfortunately, this query takes several seconds to complete. I need to optimize it so that it takes the least amount of execution time. I did a little bit of research it looks like adding an index is not helpful because it would only apply if the number is exactly the `StartRange` or `EndRange` value, but not if it's between.

Does anyone have any tips or tricks I can use to bring down the execution time? Ideally I'd want it to be under 1 second if possible.

Comment: What is your current table schema? (output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`)

Comment: Also can you post the output of `DESCRIBE SELECT ID FROM BigTable WHERE '5000000' BETWEEN StartRange AND EndRange`? That will show if your inde(x|ces) are being used.

Comment: Sure, the output is this: `1 SIMPLE BigTable ALL ID,StartRange,EndRange    5522123 Using where`

Comment: And if you create the index described in @Jocelyn's answer, do you get the same thing, or is it now using the key? I ran a small test case and the key was indeed used according to `explain`.

Comment: I've just tried that and the output is the same for the `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a table of ip address ranges and the below really did the trick for me. You'll want an index on at least StartRange.

```
SELECT ID
FROM BigTable
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(StartRange) AS start
   FROM BigTable
   WHERE StartRange <= @Target) AS s
ON StartRange = s.start
WHERE EndRange >= @Target;
```

Comment: It's been 6+ years since you posted this answer. I came here looking for a quick way to search ip address ranges (from GeoLite) as it turns out.

This answer sped up lookups by a factor of 10. THANKS!!

Answer (score 3):

Add a compound index to your table. This index must be made of the `StartRange` and `EndRange` fields:

```
ALTER TABLE `BigTable` ADD INDEX ( `StartRange` , `EndRange` );
```

Then use `EXPLAIN` on your query to check that the new index is used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ID FROM BigTable WHERE '5000000' BETWEEN StartRange AND EndRange;
```

The output shows that MySQL is unable to use the new index with this query. You may then rewrite your initial query:

```
SELECT ID FROM BigTable WHERE StartRange>='5000000' AND EndRange<='5000000'
                            OR EndRange>='5000000' AND StartRange<='5000000'
```

This new query will return the same results as your initial query. The good news are with `EXPLAIN`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ID FROM BigTable WHERE StartRange>='5000000' AND EndRange<='5000000'
                            OR EndRange>='5000000' AND StartRange<='5000000'
```

The output now shows that MySQL is able to use the new index.

Answer (score 2):

An index should handle this query just fine, even if the value does not match the `StartRange` and `EndRange`.

Comment: I concur. It should speed things up significantly.

Comment: I added an index to `StartRange` and `EndRange`, but there doesn't seem to be any speed improvements (still taking about 10 seconds for a simple query).

Comment: Then please do what Jocelyn and willoller suggest so we can debug.

Answer (score 1):

An index will not speed up this query.  Indexes can be used for BETWEEN searches but only whey they're "right way around" (eg `StartRange BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000`).

To speed up this query you're going to have to resort to some trickery.

First off, if the range table is static or does not grow rapidly, and if the range values are really integers, you could generate an extra table containing all values from the lowest StartRange to the highest EndRange along with the matching id.  Then you could search for the exact value you need.

Alternatively, calculate the largest value of EndRange - StartRange and call it MaxRange.  Create an index on StartRange and change your query to:

```
 SELECT ID FROM BigTable 
    WHERE StartRange BETWEEN ('5000000' - MaxRange) AND '5000000' 
      AND '5000000' BETWEEN StartRange AND EndRange;
```

Now, the first BETWEEN clause *is* indexable and should return a small number of rows.  The second BETWEEN clause will then be applied only to that small subset of rows.  Obviously, this relies on your being able to calculate a safe value of MaxRange in advance.  Hopefully there's some actual maximum possible value for the range that will tell you this number.

Comment: +1 Interesting... Do you happen to have a good resource for an in-depth discussion of this case? It seems that sometimes the index is used, but only the first part, and in the worst case it ends up looking at every row anyway? Or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Larry. We will investigate to see if this helps us. The first method may not be practical as that would create a table with over 9 billion rows.

Comment: That would certainly be a lot of rows.  BTW, SQL may not be the best way to solve this problem.  Have you considered something like a binary search?  You could do that from the table or, depending on the environment, maintain an in-memory structure for this particular search.